# My Web Api Rest client is forcing me to reference Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC Api endpoint, and I am creating a api rest client project also that wrap the api endpoint service.

I am using Entity framework, code first.

My web api project looks like:

```
project-mvc
project-core  (this contains entity framework, models, etc.)
```

Now when I create my rest api client project:

```
project-api-client
```

The problem is, I have to reference the project-core because it contains the models, but then I also get entity framework since it is a dependancy.

So I tried creating a seperate models project:

```
project-models
```

But it seems it still has to reference EntityFramework, otherwise my attributes don't seem to work  e.g.:

```
public class Something
{

        [Key]
        [Column("Something_ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

I thought all you needed was  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but I was forced to bring in EntityFramwork.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to decouple your layers; in general passing EF objects around and more specifically throwing them across the wire from a controller is a bad idea because you may end up exposing parts of your data model that a client has no interest (or business) in knowing.

One approach to rectify this would be as follows *(note: this example is being done on the fly and not strictly speaking the "best" or most decoupled correct method, but I wanted to vice you a push in the right direction*)

**Interfaces**
What you need to do is define an interface that describes the important properties of a MyThing that a client might want to see. You place this interface definition in a separate project (let's say "MyInterfaces") and reference this project from your EF project:

```
public interface IThing
{
   int ID{get;set;}
   string Data{get;set;}
}
```

**Data Transfer Objects**
whilst you're at it, create a concrete implementation Data Transfer Object of IThing in the Interfaces project:

```
public class MyThingDTO:IThing
{
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public string Data{get;set;}
}
```

*note: strictly speaking this model should be re-implemented in the various "layers" of your project and the interfaces project should contain only interfaces but for simplicity's sake I am using the same DTO in all layers.*

**Entities**
Now you can define an Entity in your EF project something like this

```
public class MyThing:IThing
{
   [Key]
   [Column("MyThing_ID")
   public int ID{get;set;}
   [Column("MyThing_Data")
   public string Data {Get;set;}
}
```

**Data Access Layer**
Now you can create a Data Access Layer project which references your Entity Framework and Interface projects, and create some kind of class whose job it is to service requests for IThings

```
public class MyThingDataService
{
   public IThing GetByID(int ID)
   {
      //EF code to query your database goes here, assuming you have a valid DBContext called "ctx". I won't go into how you might create or inject this, etc, as it's a separate topic e.g Dependency Injection.
     var thing = ctx.MyThings.FirstOrDefault();
     if (thing!=null)
    {
        return new MyThingDTO{ID=thing.ID, Data=thing.Data};
    }
    else{//handle the not found case here}
   }
}
```

**References**
Finally you reference your Data Access Layer and Interfaces project from your MVC project, and your controller code now looks like

```
public MyThing Get(int id)
{
   //assuming you have an instance of MyThingDataService here, injected via DI or manually created, etc.
//strictly speaking we should declare our controller return type as IMyThing 
//but this means we have to also decorate the DTO class with some attributes for the serialiser     
//(KnownType) and I don't want to confuse things, hence the cast.
   return dataService.GetByID(id) as MyThing; 
}
```

*Now the only reference to the EF project is in the central Interfaces project.*

Your client project need only reference the Interfaces project (in fact you don't actually need to do this because your client is receiving serialised data via HTTP and therefore is free to implement its own take on the IMyThing interface, but it's handy to re-use it of only to save time).

**Wrapping Up**

I mentioned that this is just a push in the right direction - to make a **truly** decoupled implementation you need to do some more work. 
 - Your Data Access Layer should also be defined by interface, and you should use some kind of DI container to inject it into the MVC controller; 
 - Your Interfaces project should contain only interfaces and each layer should implement its own concrete class to represent the data flowing through it (i.e they should all have their own flavour of MyThingDTO implementing IMyThing)
 - When you do this then you will see that you have a nicely decoupled system as none of the layers (MVC, Data Access, EF) have ANY reference to each other, only to the centralised Interfaces project.
 - Probably someone smarter than me will spot something else you need to do as I may have forgotten something - it's very early (late?) here.

Anyway. Hope this helps.

Comment: The client is our own internal apps.  But in my scenerio, the DTO and Entity would be the same thing.  I'd rather not have to duplicate/mirror the 2 classes everytime.  I think Microsoft needs to decouple the adding of attributes on a model and the Entity Framework dll!!

Comment: Fair enough re the internal apps, but the issue is not tight coupling between DataAnnotations and EF.
The reason you need to reference EntityFramework in your MVC project is because you have added a reference to your entity project which in turn has a reference to EntityFramework. If you move that `Something` class to another project and reference only DataAnnotations from there, you can then reference that project from both MVC and EF project and it should have the same effect as my solution, i.e you will just use the EF project to setup and define your DBContext/DBSet for `Something`

Comment: I created a seperate project, copied JUST my models there, and the Column attribute was giving me an error, and resharper suggested to reference EntityFramework.  `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` was not enough...

Comment: You need to add a reference to the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Assembly (.dll) yourself, and then in your code file
`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Then you will be able to use the Key and Column attributes...ReSharper was probably being a bit too helpful. If you can't get it working I have a sample (console) project using pure code-first with basically the same setup as described above and it works just fine with no reference to EF anywhere in my top layer. Let me know if you want it.